# Media query when max-width is set to 767px

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this `HTML/CSS`:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <style>
            p{
                color: white;
                background: black;
            }

            @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
                p {
                    color: yellow;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>SOME TEXT</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am using Chrome - mobile mode or I can resize the browser window, it is same.

When I make the width of the screen `767 pixels`, the color of `p` tag is `white` (the  style in media query not applied). When I make the screen width - `766 pixels`, the color is yellow (media query style applied), but in `CSS` I have - `.. and (max-width: 767px)`. `767 pixels` width isn't included.

If I set in my `CSS` - `and (max-width: 768px)` and make the screen width `768 pixels`, the color of the `p` tag is `yellow`, which means `768 pixels` width is included.

Why is that ?

The problem here is with Bootstrap, because the class `col-sm-*` is for `(min-width: 768px)` and the class `.col-xs-*` apply when the width of the screen is maximum `767px`(767 included, but in the Bootstrap CSS file, they don't use media query for this class).

I want style to be added when the width is max 767 pixels (when `col-xs-*` is active), but if I set `max-width:767px`, my style will be added when the width of the screen is `766 pixels`. If I set the style - `max-width:768px`, it will add the style when the width is `768 pixels`.

How can I add style for width `<= 767 pixels` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution for you is to add `max width: 767.5px`. It will work. But in general I would suggest avoiding using both min-width and max-width, ideally, you should write your styles mobile first, and after that modify with `min-width` media queries (min-width: 768px, min-width: 992px, etc...)